# Homogeneous Equation with Constant Coefficients clarification

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was given a sample problem$$y′′ − 4y′ + 4y = 0$$

I understand how the answer came out to be $$c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t}$$. My professor explained how we only got one solution when completing the square but we need two. So we have to use the method of Reduction of Order to get the final answer.

My question relates to whether the final answer (with the "t" variable in it) is a formula or not? I tried with another simple problem and got a similar answer. I researched online but could not find anything concrete.
So when you have one number (when y is one number) as an answer for this type of equation with constant coefficients, is the answer a  formula like$$c_1e^{at}+c_2te^{at}$$

Comment: If your root $\lambda$ is of n-th order then $e^{\lambda t}, te^{\lambda t}, \dots, t^{n-1}e^{\lambda t}$ is the part of the fundamental system to your linear ODE, which is related to $\lambda$, with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is:

1. Transform the differential equation into a polynomial $p(\lambda)$ by replacing $y$ with $\lambda^0$, $y'$ with $\lambda^1$ and so on (the $i$-th derivative with the $i$-th power.
2. Solve $p(\lambda)=0$ for $\lambda$. What you get are $n$ values of $\lambda$ that solve the equation, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial. However, some of the $\lambda$-s may be duplicate (or more than that) - $\lambda^4-1$ has *one* zero, but it is quadruple (its algebraic multiplicity is $4$).
3. Let's say the polynomial has zeroes $\lambda_1,\dots\lambda_k$ with multiplicity $m_1,\dots, m_k$.
4. Your final solution is $$P_1(t)e^{\lambda_1t} + P_2(t)e^{\lambda_2t} + \cdots + P_k(t)e^{\lambda_kt}$$

where $P_1,\dots, P_k$ are polynomials and for each $i$, $P_i$ has degree at most $m_i-1$.

So, in your case, $k=1$ and $\lambda_1=-2$, while $m_1=2$ (double zero), so your final solution is $$(At+B)e^{2t}$$
for some pair $A,B\in\mathbb R$ (which, more or less, is what your professor's solution is)

---

To remember that formula, you can see that $$P_1(t)e^{\lambda_1t} + P_2(t)e^{\lambda_2t} + \cdots + P_k(t)e^{\lambda_kt}$$ is actually a linear combination of $e^{\lambda_it}, te^{\lambda_it}, \dots, t^{m_i-1}e^{\lambda_it}$ for every $i$, i.e. for every root of your original equation.

In your case, this is a combination of $e^{2t}$ and $te^{2t}$ (which, more or less, is what your professor's solution is)

Comment: +1: Nice compact representation using polynomials :).

Comment: @MrYouMath Thanks. I find that the most compact way of writing it, while the "linear combination of $e^{\lambda t}, te^{\lambda t}$ and so on up to one less than the multiplicity of that $\lambda$" is maybe easier to remember, but takes ages to write down :)

Comment: I also never liked the linear combination ... but never thought about representing it as a polynomial :). Really nice answer :).

Answer (score 1):

To solve:

$$y''(t)−4y'(t)+4y(t)=0$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y''(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}-4\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[y'(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}+4\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[y(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{(\text{s})}$$

Use:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y''(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{s}^2\text{Y}(\text{s})-\text{s}y(0)-y'(0)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y'(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{s}\text{Y}(\text{s})-y(0)$$
3. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[y(t)\right]_{(\text{s})}=\text{Y}(\text{s})$$
4. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[0\right]_{(\text{s})}=0$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\text{Y}(\text{s})-\text{s}y(0)-y'(0)-4\cdot\left(\text{s}\text{Y}(\text{s})-y(0)\right)+4\text{Y}(\text{s})=0$$

Solving $\text{Y}(\text{s})$:

$$\text{Y}(\text{s})=\frac{y'(0)+y(0)\left(\text{s}-4\right)}{\left(\text{s}-2\right)^2}$$

Using inverse Laplace transform, we get:

$$y(t)=e^{2t}\left(y(0)-2ty(0)+ty'(0)\right)$$